# Hide component onClick using state with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, onclick

I'm trying to hide StickyFooterDynamic onCLick. I've managed to hide it with css but I'd like to use React's state to completely remove it from the DOM onClick. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to do this? ES6 way.

```
class StickyFooterDynamic extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
  visible: true,
}
}

onClick() {
this.setState(prevState => ({
  visible: !prevState.visible,
}))
}

render() {

if (!this.state.visible) {
  return null
}

const { url, service } = this.props;

return (
  <StickyFooter>
    <div className='sticky-footer-dynamic-wrapper'>
      <div className='main-content'>
        <div className='copy-wrapper'>
          <img className='sticky-footer-dynamic-img' alt='Repair Icon' src={iconRepair} />
          <h3 className='sticky-footer-copy'>Want a free quote for {service}?</h3>
        </div>
        <a className='sticky-footer-dynamic-btn btn' href={url}>GET<i className="right-arrow"></i></a>
        <a href='#' className='sticky-footer-close' onClick={this.onClick}></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </StickyFooter>
);
}
}

export default StickyFooterDynamic;
```

Comment: I'd like to use the a tag with class 'sticky-footer-close' as the button with onClick function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can toggle inner state and return `null` instead:

```
class StickyFooterDynamic extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      visible: true,
    }

    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this)
  }

  onClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      visible: !prevState.visible,
    }))
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.visible) {
      return null
    }

    const { url, service } = this.props

    return (
      <StickyFooter>
        ...
        <a href="#" className='sticky-footer-close' onClick={this.onClick}></a>
      </StickyFooter>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! StickyFooterDynamic doesn't have any parent component. It's rendered on a haml page. Also I'd like to use the a tag with class 'sticky-footer-close' as the button with onClick function.

Comment: @Patrick1904 so which part of this component you want to hide?  From `StickyFooter` down?

Comment: I'd like to hide the whole component (StickyFooterDynamic), if possible. And to do everything within this component.

Comment: @Patrick1904 I've updated my answer. Please check whether that helps you or not :)

Comment: It doesn't work for me. "Cannot read property 'setState' of null"

Any ideas?

Comment: @Patrick1904 are you initializing `state` in the constructor? Are you also binding `onClick` method?

Comment: I updated my question with your code. See anything wrong?

Comment: @Patrick1904 yep. In the constructor, you need to add `this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this)`

Comment: Great! That works. Thank you! Do you know where I can add preventdefault so that screen doesn't scroll to top when clicking the close btn?

Comment: In `onClick` :) Please check my answer

Comment: Perfect. Much appreciated!